# use VPN for external connections and not use for LAN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I have three 'devices' 
en0 (wi-fi)
en4 (thunderbolt)
ppp0 (pptp)

in VPN settings, send all traffic over VPN enabled.
Service order in main network settings window is: Thund., Wi-Fi, VPN (PPTP)

After I connect to VPN server, all my traffic goes over it :)

But i would make exception, like local traffic do not send over VPN.

After I connect to VPN I have next routing table

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            link#14            UCS           192        0    ppp0
default            localgatewayIP     UGScI           0        0     en0
default            localgatewayIP     UGScI           7        0     en4
```

How to add rule that by default over ppp0 except specific subnet which I would like send over en0, for instance.

Thanks.

Comment: so you want "everything over vpn except local stuff", as opposed to "nothing over vpn except that which is only accessible from the vpn"?

Comment: @RussellUhl yes